# Apply Remote Commits to a Local Pull Request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have forked an active open source project that is on GitHub to my account. I then cloned my GH repo to my local machine. I do regular fetches of the upstream master branch to keep my local copy in sync.

I’m interested a pull request for a significant new feature on the upstream repo that is currently being reviewed and changed. I want to copy the pull request to my local machine so I can review and analyze this code. I will not be submitting any changes to this work.

I’ve fetched the pull request with this command and result:

```
$ git fetch upstream pull/5737/head:pr-5737 

remote: Counting objects: 4, done. 
remote: Total 4 (delta 3), reused 3 (delta 3), pack-reused 1 
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done. 
From https://github.com/OrigProj/repo-name 
* [new ref]     refs/pull/5737/head -> pr-5737
```

The result is a new branch called ‘pr-5737’ for the pull request.  The project devs have now made additional commits to the pull request as they work on it. I can get the new commits to the pull request down to my local machine with these commands:

```
$ git checkout pr-5737 
Switched to branch 'pr-5737' 

$ git fetch upstream pull/5737/head

remote: Counting objects: 4, done. 
remote: Total 4 (delta 3), reused 3 (delta 3), pack-reused 1 
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done. 
From https://github.com/OrigProj/repo-name
* branch         refs/pull/5737/head -> FETCH_HEAD
```

I cannot figure out the command to ‘merge’ these newly fetched commits to the head of the pull request branch. I don’t want to merge the pull request into the master branch. I want to keep the separate branch, pr-5737, updated. What command do I use?

I know I can just delete the pull request branch, pr-5737, and re-fetch it but that doesn’t seem like the ‘correct’ way to do things.

## Answer:

Cherry-Picking from the excellent explanation/answer by torek. And taking the easy path based on my current practice. I was able to add new commits from upstream to the pull request branch, pr-5737.

I used these commands:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch -f pr-5737 FETCH_HEAD
```

I then pushed everything to my GitHub fork of the upstream project. Mainly for reasons of a backup. You will also see I have added two other pull-request branches I wanted.

```
$ git push  -v --all origin
Pushing to git@github.com:username/fork-project.git
Enter passphrase for key '/home/acct-name/.ssh/id_ecdsa':                                                                                                                   
Counting objects: 68, done.                                                                                                                                             
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.                                                                                                                                
Compressing objects: 100% (68/68), done.                                                                                                                                
Writing objects: 100% (68/68), 11.38 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.                                                                                                             
Total 68 (delta 50), reused 0 (delta 0)                                                                                                                                 
 remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (50/50), completed with 21 local objects.
To git@github.com:username/fork-project.git                                                                                                                                
 = [up to date]      pr-5717 -> pr-5717                                                                                                                                 
   ec0b073..67486dc  master -> master                                                                                                                                   
   212c54a..e935946  pr-5737 -> pr-5737                                                                                                                                 
 * [new branch]      pr-5763 -> pr-5763                                                                                                                                 
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'                                                                                                                
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/pr-5717'                                                                                                               
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/pr-5737'                                                                                                               
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/pr-5763'
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing things that are not "built in" to Git, so there is not necessarily a *correct* way.  There are merely a lot of options.  There *is* a way—or multiple ways, really—to deal with this that *is* built-in, so you might want to switch to that, but let's get there by starting with what you are doing.

Let's look first at what happens when you run `git fetch`.  I'll assume here that you have *two* remotes, one named `origin` and the other named `upstream`.  Here's what these remote names do for you:

- Each remembers a URL.

  The URL for `origin` and the URL for `upstream` are different, and do not even both need to be on GitHub (although since you mention GitHub forks, I assume both are).  You get to type in a shorter name, though.
- Each also provides a prefix for *remote-tracking branch names*.  You now have both `origin/master` and `upstream/master`, for instance.

It's this second part that you can (in management-speak) "leverage" for the pull requests.  But first, let's talk about branches, branch names, and name spaces.

#### Git branches vs Git branch names

The term *branch*, in Git, is ambiguous.  It can mean a branch *name* like `master` or `pr-5737`, but it can also refer to a branch structure within the commit graph.  Each commit has its own unique hash ID, and each commit also records the ID of a previous commit.  For instance, in a new repository with just three commits, we might have:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
```

where the name `master` contains the ID of commit `C`, and `C` itself contains the ID of commit `B`.  We say that `master` *points to* `C`, `C` points to `B`, and `B` points to `A`.  Since `A` is the very first commit, there's nothing for it to point back to; we call this a *root* commit.  These pointers all work backwards—the branch name finds the *tip* commit for us (and for Git), and the tip commit finds an earlier commit, which finds more commits, all the way back to the root.

Adding a new commit simply means writing a commit that points back to the current tip, and then updating the branch name to point to the new commit:

```
A <- B <- C <- D   <-- master
```

I generally draw these without the internal backwards arrows, which makes the drawing more compact and allows displaying branches:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
    \
     E--F    <-- feature
```

Note, again, that the branch *names* only point to the (two, in this case) *tip* commits.  It's those commits that point back to the rest of the commits.  These chains of commits are also Git branches.  For more on this, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  We use the term *branch* interchangeably, in Git, to mean both branch *names* and branch *structures* within the commit graph.  It's usually obvious which one is meant—though if it's not, you should ask!

One key item here is that commits can be pointed-to by things that are names, but are not *branch* names.  For instance, tags can also point to commits (and of course commits point to commits).  There are very few restrictions on these names, and in fact, pull requests are just yet another category of names that point to commits.  The general term for all of these is *references:* in Git, a reference is any name for a commit—usually the tip commit of a branch (the graph branch)—or any other Git object (but we'll ignore the three other types of Git objects here).<sup>1</sup>

The other key item is that in normal (non-maintenance-command) usage, Git can *only* get started, in terms of finding commits in the commit graph, using these names.  It needs a branch name, or tag name, or *something*, to find a starting ID.  (You can give your Git a raw ID, possibly abbreviated, which is what you do if you run `git log ac0ffee` for instance.  It starts from that commit and works backwards from there.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Some parts of Git assert that all references start with `refs/`, but others note that there are special non-`refs/` references, such as `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, and so on.  I would put it as *most* references start with `refs/`.

---

#### `git fetch` brings in commits

When you run `git fetch`, you have your Git call up another Git.  That other Git has its own repository.  Your Git uses the URL stored in under the remote name to contact the other Git, and then your Git and their Git have a little conversation.  Their Git tells your Git about their branch tips—the names, and the commits—the hash IDs—identified by those names.

These hash IDs are computed, in a complicated (cryptographic) but fully deterministic way, from the *contents* of the commits.  Any two commits that are 100% identical, bit-for-bit, have the *same* IDs.  This means that any commits that your Git and their Git both have in both repositories, have the same IDs.  So, your Git can tell if you already have their commits, or not.

If your Git doesn't have their commits, and you've told your Git to bring them in (by asking for that name, or all names), your Git then requests those commits from their Git.  Their Git bundles them up and sends them over, and your Git stores them in your repository, using their unique hash IDs.

#### Fetch must now assign names

Git now needs some way to *find* these commits, now that it *has* these commits.  This means that `git fetch` must save some names.  Of course, *all* of the branch tips and other tip commits that your Git got from the other Git, had names over there.  Why can't it just use those names?

Think about this for a moment and the reason becomes obvious.  Suppose the name it got was "branch master", and it *overwrote* your `master` with this new value.  You'd lose easy access to your own commits!<sup>2</sup>

The simplest way for `git fetch` to save these name/ID pairs is to write them all into a file named `FETCH_HEAD`.  They will stay there, safe and sound, until the next `git fetch` overwrites them.

That's what you are doing with this (second) command:

> ```
> $ git fetch upstream pull/5737/head
> remote: Counting objects: 4, done. 
> remote: Total 4 (delta 3), reused 3 (delta 3), pack-reused 1 
> Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done. 
> From https://github.com/OrigProj/repo-name
> * branch         refs/pull/5737/head -> FETCH_HEAD
> ```

The `remote:` messages are coming from that other Git: it's packaged up four objects (probably one commit, one tree, and two blobs, though I am just guessing) into a *thin pack* with delta compression applied ("delta 3").  Your Git got the package and unpacked it.  Your Git used one name from their Git—`refs/pull/5737/head`—just as you told it to.  And, your Git did not store this under *your own* name, but merely in the `FETCH_HEAD` file.

If you like, you can now extract this commit's ID from the file `FETCH_HEAD`.  You can do that by looking inside the file (the format will be reasonably obvious), or—since there's only one ID in it—just by using the name `FETCH_HEAD`.  Just remember that the *next* fetch will overwrite the file, forgetting the ID.  Once this forgetting happens, if the new commit you just got has *no* names that can find it, that makes the commit eligible for *garbage collection*: it will eventually get thrown away.  But you have a chance, now, to give it your own name(s).

Let's compare, though, to your *first* command:

> ```
> $ git fetch upstream pull/5737/head:pr-5737
> ```

Note the colon here, and that the output ended with:

> ```
> * [new ref]     refs/pull/5737/head -> pr-5737
> ```

The earlier command did not say `FETCH_HEAD`.  Your Git wrote the name, instead, to a new reference, `pr-5737`.  This reference is in fact `refs/heads/pr-5737`, through some assumptions that `git fetch` makes.<sup>3</sup>  For now, let's just note that the "full name" of any branch is `refs/heads/branch`, e.g., `refs/heads/master` for the branch-name `master`.

This colon-separated form, by the way, is a *refspec*.  A refspec is only slightly more or less than a pair of branch names: a source name, and a destination.  With `git fetch`, the source is *their* name (branch or other reference), and the destination is *your* name.  You may choose any kind of name, not just a branch name, for either side.  For `fetch`, leaving out the destination name like this means you want to just write the information to `FETCH_HEAD`.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>But note that this *is* (partly) how *tags* work.  The idea of tags is to be global across all repository clones.  The question then becomes whether and when your own tags will be overwritten by another Git's tags, and the answer to that is complicated (and not appropriate for this posting).

<sup>3</sup>Both `git fetch` and `git push` have some complicated code to *qualify* an *unqualified* reference.  A name like `master` or `branch` or `pr-5737` does not start with `refs/`, so it is unqualified.  If you write out `refs/pull/5737/head` or similar, this *does* start with `refs/` and is qualified, and does not go through this complicated bit of code.  In a few cases, Git can't do the qualification on its own, or does it wrong, and makes you write out the full name.  That's true for these pull names, for instance.  Usually, though, it does pretty well at guessing whether something is a branch or a tag.  In this case, it guesses that you meant to make a branch, which is probably correct.

<sup>4</sup>Since Git version 1.8.2, Git will do an *opportunistic update* of remote-tracking branches.  We'll see more about this at the very end of this article.

---

#### Fast-forwarding and force-updating

> I cannot figure out the command to ‘merge’ these newly fetched commits to the head of the pull request branch.

It's time to go back to the graph drawings.

Your first `git fetch` brought in some commits—probably just one, again—but it gave them a branch name in your repository, `pr-5737`.  That commit itself points back to a previous commit, which I'll guess for now is one that is mainly or only on their (`upstream`'s) branch `master`.  The graph fragment is therefore:

```
...--o     <-- upstream/master
      \
       o   <-- pr-5737
```

Now, it may be that you have already updated your own `master` to match `upstream/master`.  In that case, we should draw the graph this way:

```
...--o     <-- master, upstream/master
      \
       o   <-- pr-5737
```

*Note that the commit graph is unchanged!*  All we did was change the *labels* a bit.  That's the key to this process.  The fetch will *always* get you the commits; what you want to do is to change (or perhaps add) labels, such as branch names, as you incorporate these commits into your own graph.  The `fetch` step modifies—*adds to*—the commit graph, and after that, we need something to happen with *names*.

So, let's look at the graph after the *second* `git fetch`.  First, let's assume this adds one more commit that points back to the previous pull-request commit:

```
...--o       <-- upstream/master
      \
       o     <-- pr-5737
        \
         o   <-- FETCH_HEAD
```

In this case, you probably want to move `pr-5737` to point to the same commit as `FETCH_HEAD`.  But, what if the new commit *doesn't* point back to the previous pull-request commit?  What if instead, it points to the `origin/master` commit?  Well, let's draw that:

```
...--o     <-- upstream/master
     |\
     | o   <-- pr-5737
     |
      \
       o   <-- FETCH_HEAD
```

Now you probably want to move `pr-5737` to point to the new commit.  (Or, maybe you *don't* want that: it's up to *you* to decide what you want.  But I'll assume that you do want it.)

There are a bunch of Git commands that will move a branch label.  The most user-oriented is `git branch`: with `git branch --force` you can re-set any branch that you don't currently have checked out.  (To re-set the branch you *do* have checked-out, you need to use `git reset` instead, for a bunch of good technical reasons that amount to Git letting the implementation show through.)  You could just run:

```
git branch -f pr-5737 FETCH_HEAD
```

to forcibly move the name `pr-5737` to point to the commit `git fetch` just brought in.

(Again, if you have `pr-5737` checked out at the moment, you have to use `git reset` instead, and then you must choose: `--soft`, `--mixed`, or `--hard`?  These control whether the reset operation affects the index and work-tree.  Let's just assume that you don't have it checked out. :-) )

Now, *if* the new commit we just brought in, the one at `FETCH_HEAD`, "adds to the branch"—i.e., the new commit(s) point(s) back to the tip of `pr-5737`—this branch label movement is what Git calls a *fast-forward*.  Note how, in the first `FETCH_HEAD` drawing above, Git can kind of slide the label forward (rightward, while also going down) to the new commit:

```
...--o       <-- upstream/master
      \
       o
        \
         o   <-- pr-5737, FETCH_HEAD
```

With the second drawing, however, forcing `pr-5737` to point to the new commit causes the old one to be forgotten!  We have to back the label up one step, to point to the tip of `upstream/master`, and then back down and right.  This is a non-fast-forward *forced* update.

If we use `git branch -f`, it will update `pr-5737` even if it cannot be fast-forwarded.  What if you only want to move `pr-5737` if it's a fast-forward?

#### Merge can also fast-forward

You have no doubt seen Git print "Fast-forward" when merging.  This is because if you are on one of your branches, and run `git merge name`, Git will check whether the commit it finds under the given *`name`*—usually, the tip of a branch—is "fast-forward ahead" of the tip commit of the *current* branch.  If so, Git doesn't actually merge anything, it just slides the branch name forward (and checks out the new commit, so that your index and work-tree match the new branch tip).

If you use the `git merge` command, you can *limit* it to working *only* if the merge will really be a fast-forward instead, using `--ff-only`.  (And, you can force it not to do a fast-forward at all, but rather make a new *merge commit*, using `--no-ff`.)  So, you could `git checkout pr-5737` and then `git merge --ff-only FETCH_HEAD` to make the fast-forward happen.  Of course, this could fail, as it would for the second case.  Then you have to decide what you want to do.

You probably *don't* want to merge these two commits.  (If you really do, for whatever reason, you *can*: just run `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.  That's probably not *useful* though.)  You probably just want to force the branch to move and to load the new tip commit into your index and work-tree, in which case, you can `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD`.  If you go this way, though, you'll know—based on whether `git merge --ff-only` worked—whether the updated pull request is a replacement, or an add-on.

#### Doing it the easy way: `git fetch` can do it for you

In your original `git fetch` you told your Git to write the name `pr-5737`:

> ```
> $ git fetch upstream pull/5737/head:pr-5737
> ```

You can use this exact same command again.  Your Git will obtain any new commit(s), and then try to update your existing `refs/heads/pr-5737`.

As before, this could be a fast-forward.  In this case, your Git will do the update.  (You still get a `FETCH_HEAD` file but you don't need it any more.)  Or, it could be a non-fast-forward.  In this case, your Git will error-out:

```
 ! [rejected]   refs/heads/pr-5737 -> pr-5737 (non-fast-forward)
```

To *force* the update, we use one more feature of a refspec: it can start with a plus sign, which means "force".  So:

```
git fetch upstream +pull/5737/head:pr-5737
```

This time, you'll get the update, with the annotation `(forced update)` added.  The annotation is only added if the update is actually forced, so as with doing a manual `git merge --ff-only`, you will *know* whether the update had to be forced.

#### The really easy, fully automated way

Now, it might be nice if you could get `git fetch` to do this update without having to type:

```
git fetch upstream +pull/5737/head:pr-5737
```

all the time.  And there is—and in fact, you can bring in any and all pull requests that have the form `refs/pull/NNNN/head`, or any other form you care to recognize.  It's up to you to decide how to bring them in, but before we dive into the mechanism, let's mention *name spaces*, and the role of a *remote* name in *remote-tracking branch* names.

A name space (or [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) as a single word) is an organization, typically hierarchical, where different groups of names are, well, grouped.  In Git's case, for instance, most references are under `refs/`, but *all* branch names are under `refs/heads/`, as we saw earlier.  All tags are under `refs/tags/`.  These names work like directories (and are actually implemented as such, in some cases).  The space beginning with `refs/remotes/` holds all remote-tracking branch names, but it's further subdivided: there is one space for the remote named `origin`, under `refs/remotes/origin/`, and another for `upstream`, under `refs/remotes/upstream/`.

By sub-dividing the remote-tracking branches, and separating them from your regular branches, Git guarantees that it will never use, as a remote-tracking branch name, any of your own branch names.  Your own branches all start with `refs/heads/`, and `refs/remotes/origin/` does not start with `refs/heads/`, so these names are separate.  Moreover, by including the name of the remote, Git tries to guarantee that these also never collide: `refs/remotes/origin/` is always different from `refs/remotes/upstream`.<sup>5</sup>

If you allow *pull requests*, of the form `pr-number`, to occupy the *same* name space as your branches, *and* if you name one of your own branches, say, `pr-123`, you can get a collision.  So don't do that: either make sure you never name your branches like this, or pick your own name space for your pull-request-trackers.  You may want to stick with branch names since Git only has three built-in forms it recognizes, for branches, tags, and remote-tracking branches; so branch names are shorter to type.  (That's why you had to spell out `pull/5737/head` rather than just `5737/head`: the full name is `refs/pull/5737/head`, and Git can find this under `refs`, but not without the `pull` part.  Your `master`'s full name is `refs/heads/master`, but you don't *have* to type in `heads/master`.)

(For reasons I will mention in a moment, you might want to spell your dedicated pull-request sub-branch name space `pr/*` instead of `pr-*`.  I'll assume from now on, you want `pr/5737` instead of `pr-5737`.)

If you open your `.git/config` file in your editor—note that you can do this with `git config --edit`, so Git kind of encourages this; it's relatively safe as long as your editor does not try to convert the configuration to rich text or something equally silly—you will see a configuration section for each remote:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "upstream"]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

The `url` lines provide the saved URLs—they are *how* your Git knows how to call up the other Git.  The more interesting lines, for us, are the `fetch` ones.  These provide the *default* fetch refspecs.

If you run `git fetch origin`, that *means*

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This is *how* Git implements the remote-tracking branches: a `git fetch` just obtains the refspecs you gave it, even if those are the ones implied by the per-remote `fetch` default configuration.  Git also allows more than one `fetch =` line, and it adds *all* of them as the default set of refspecs.

This shows that refspecs can also do a kind of wild-card matching.  This matching is a limited form of shell style *glob* match.   This means you can add a second `fetch =` line that reads:

```
+refs/pull/*/head:refs/heads/pr/*
```

Now, if the remote has a reference named `refs/pull/5737/head` when you run `git fetch`, *your* Git will create or update—forcibly if needed—your own branch `pr/5737`.

If your Git is new enough, you can use one `*` glob pretty much anywhere, e.g., the rather peculiar:

```
+refs/pull/5*/head:refs/heads/pr-5*
```

which will obtain only pull requests starting with `5`, updating your own branch name starting with `pr-5`.  But in versions of Git before 2.6.0 ([commit cd377f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd377f45c9d06e8ab3e87d5a687ed22ab34e1c48)), the `*` had to match a whole component, e.g., `pull/*/head` but not `pull/5*/head`, or `pr/*` but not `pr-*`.  If your Git is 2.6.0 or later, you can fetch to `pr-*`, but if not, you must fetch to `pr/*`.

(Since Git version 1.8.2, if Git is fetching a reference, and it has one of these matching `fetch =` lines, your Git will update the corresponding remote-tracking branch, automatically, even if you gave some refspecs on the command line.  This does not occur in older versions of Git.  But even in those older versions of Git, if you succeed at a `git push` that pushes something matching one of these refspecs, Git will opportunistically update the remote-tracking branch.  The fact that push did it was what finally convinced the Git folks that fetch should do it too.)

---

<sup>5</sup>This attempt fails in subtle ways if you name one remote `a` and another `a/b`.  Git should forbid slashes in remote names, but it doesn't.  (So, don't use slashes in remote names—or if you do, make sure none is ever a prefix of another.)

---

#### There are more options

You don't have to make the pull requests into (regular) branches.  You could add them as remote-tracking branches, for instance, using your own invented `pr/` sub-name-space:

```
[remote "upstream"]
    +refs/pull/*:+refs/remotes/pr/upstream/*
```

This will turn their `pull/5737/head` into your `pr/upstream/5737/head` *remote-tracking* branch.  You can now choose whether to `git checkout 5737/head` to create your own local branch named `5737/head` that has the remote-tracking branch `pr/upstream/5737/head` (this is for a "remote" named `pr/upstream`—which you don't have, but that's fine; though you *will* have to be sure not to name a new remote "pr")—as its upstream.  (That is, `5737/head@{u}` will name `pr/upstream/5737/head`.)

The obvious drawback is that the name is a bit clunky.  A less obvious one is that if you collect pull requests from multiple remotes, `5737/head` might match both `pr/upstream/5737/head` *and* `pr/another/5737/head` remote-tracking branches, if both remotes have a pull request #5737 outstanding.  In this case the `git checkout` DWIM feature, that knows how to create local branches based on remote-tracking branches, will fail: it won't pick one arbitrarily for you.

There's also no clear advantage to this.  You get your own branch, so you can make your own commits—but why would you *want* to?  The drawback to force-fetching into your own branch space, using the earlier scheme without remote-tracking branches, is that you might clobber your own commits if you forget that `pr/5737` is set up this way and make some commit there that you wanted to keep.  (But even then, your `pr/5737` reflog will preserve your commit for 30 days by default.)

Hence, I am not sure why you might want this—but it's an option.  The `fetch = ...` mechanism is just that: a mechanism, not a policy.  It's up to you how to use it.

Comment: A very helpful and understandable. You greatly improved my understanding of my situation. The explanation about namespaces and name collisions will be good for the future. Still need to do back over it again to fully absorb. I'll likely create another clone repo and try out this method too.

For now, this pull request has nine new commits to the PR branch. I want to fetch them. Then ensuring I'm not on the PR branch, force the branch name to move to the last commit (?) of FETCH_HEAD with these commands:

`git checkout master` and 
`git branch -f pr-5737 FETCH-HEAD`
Will try tomorrow.

Comment: The last command has a typo. It should be: `git branch -f pr-5737 FETCH_HEAD` .  It appears this did indeed do the job I was expecting. The new commits to the PR were added to the pr-5737 (it moved the label to the tip). Was also able to push everything to my GH fork. Thanks!